Drools 9 with JDK 17 failed to execute KieContainer
We're currently migrating drools 7 to drools 9 using JAVA 17 with two separate project, one for spring-boot and one for rules jar that generated a kjar in local m2. In drools 7 this works without any issue.
Both projects able to successfully build and run upon executing mvn: clean install and mvn spring-boot:run. The main problem happens when executing the generated jar. It seems that it cannot find the a valid kieModule in the classPath then defaults to a default artifact that doesn't exist (more details below).
Here are the stacktrace:


  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.3.2)

2024-08-16T16:14:18.217+08:00  INFO 90138 --- [drools-test] [           main] com.drools.test.DroolsTestApplication    : Starting DroolsTestApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 17.0.11 with PID 90138 (/Users/isaacjones/IdeaProjects/drools-test/target/drools-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by isaacjones in /Users/isaacjones/IdeaProjects/drools-test)
2024-08-16T16:14:18.220+08:00  INFO 90138 --- [drools-test] [           main] com.drools.test.DroolsTestApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-08-16T16:57:12.607+08:00  INFO 90138 --- [drools-test] [           main] o.d.c.k.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl   : Adding KieModule from classpath: nested:/Users/isaacjones/IdeaProjects/drools-test/target/drools-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar/!BOOT-INF/lib/drools-rules-test-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
2024-08-16T16:57:13.219+08:00  WARN 90138 --- [drools-test] [           main] o.d.c.k.b.impl.ClasspathKieProject       : Unable to find pom.properties in /Users/isaacjones/IdeaProjects/drools-test/target/drools-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar/!BOOT-INF/lib/drools-rules-test-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
2024-08-16T16:57:13.249+08:00  WARN 90138 --- [drools-test] [           main] o.k.m.i.embedder.MavenSettings           : Environment variable M2_HOME is not set
2024-08-16T16:57:16.928+08:00  INFO 90138 --- [drools-test] [           main] o.d.c.k.b.impl.ClasspathKieProject       : Recursed up folders, found and used pom.xml /Users/isaacjones/IdeaProjects/drools-test/pom.xml
2024-08-16T16:57:16.930+08:00  INFO 90138 --- [drools-test] [           main] o.d.c.k.b.i.InternalKieModuleProvider    : Creating KieModule for artifact com.drools:drools-test:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
2024-08-16T16:57:16.950+08:00  WARN 90138 --- [drools-test] [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kieContainer' defined in class path resource [com/drools/test/DroolsConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer]: Factory method 'kieContainer' threw exception with message: begin 50, end 49, length 49
2024-08-16T16:57:16.959+08:00  INFO 90138 --- [drools-test] [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-08-16T16:57:16.985+08:00 ERROR 90138 --- [drools-test] [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kieContainer' defined in class path resource [com/drools/test/DroolsConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer]: Factory method 'kieContainer' threw exception with message: begin 50, end 49, length 49
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:648) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:485) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:971) ~[spring-context-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625) ~[spring-context-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at com.drools.test.DroolsTestApplication.main(DroolsTestApplication.java:10) ~[!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:91) ~[drools-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:53) ~[drools-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) ~[drools-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer]: Factory method 'kieContainer' threw exception with message: begin 50, end 49, length 49
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:178) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:644) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 50, end 49, length 49
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:4606) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2709) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2682) ~[na:na]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ZipKieModule.processEntry(ZipKieModule.java:189) ~[drools-compiler-9.44.0.Final.jar!/:9.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ZipKieModule.processZipEntries(ZipKieModule.java:173) ~[drools-compiler-9.44.0.Final.jar!/:9.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ZipKieModule.processFolderInZipFile(ZipKieModule.java:165) ~[drools-compiler-9.44.0.Final.jar!/:9.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ZipKieModule.processZipUrl(ZipKieModule.java:148) ~[drools-compiler-9.44.0.Final.jar!/:9.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ZipKieModule.processZipEntries(ZipKieModule.java:129) ~[drools-compiler-9.44.0.Final.jar!/:9.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ZipKieModule.indexZipFile(ZipKieModule.java:107) ~[drools-compiler-9.44.0.Final.jar!/:9.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ZipKieModule.<init>(ZipKieModule.java:55) ~[drools-compiler-9.44.0.Final.jar!/:9.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.InternalKieModuleProvider$DrlBasedKieModuleProvider.createKieModule(InternalKieModuleProvider.java:47) ~[drools-compiler-9.44.0.Final.jar!/:9.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.InternalKieModuleProvider.get(InternalKieModuleProvider.java:60) ~[drools-compiler-9.44.0.Final.jar!/:9.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.createInternalKieModule(ClasspathKieProject.java:223) ~[drools-compiler-9.44.0.Final.jar!/:9.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.fetchKModule(ClasspathKieProject.java:219) ~[drools-compiler-9.44.0.Final.jar!/:9.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.fetchKModule(ClasspathKieProject.java:163) ~[drools-compiler-9.44.0.Final.jar!/:9.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl.checkClasspathForKieModule(KieRepositoryImpl.java:185) ~[drools-compiler-9.44.0.Final.jar!/:9.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl.getKieModule(KieRepositoryImpl.java:132) ~[drools-compiler-9.44.0.Final.jar!/:9.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl.getKieModule(KieRepositoryImpl.java:115) ~[drools-compiler-9.44.0.Final.jar!/:9.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:190) ~[drools-compiler-9.44.0.Final.jar!/:9.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:178) ~[drools-compiler-9.44.0.Final.jar!/:9.44.0.Final]
    at com.drools.test.DroolsConfiguration.kieContainer(DroolsConfiguration.java:18) ~[!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.drools.test.DroolsConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$kieContainer$0(<generated>) ~[!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.drools.test.DroolsConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$FastClass$$1.invoke(<generated>) ~[!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258) ~[spring-core-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:348) ~[spring-context-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at com.drools.test.DroolsConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.kieContainer(<generated>) ~[!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:146) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    ... 26 common frames omitted

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52353', transport: 'socket'


drools-rules project pom

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-rules-test</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>kjar</packaging>
    <name>drools-rules-test</name>
    <description>drools-rules-test</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <drools.version>9.44.0.Final</drools.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-internal</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
                <artifactId>kie-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${drools.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


drools-test project pom
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>drools-test</name>
    <description>drools-test</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <com.bpi.drools.rules.customerriskscoringrules.version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        </com.bpi.drools.rules.customerriskscoringrules.version>
        <drools.version>9.44.0.Final</drools.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-rules-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-mvel</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-xml-support</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


We have empty Kmodule.xml in Meta-INF folder
DroolsConfiguration
package com.drools.test;

import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.builder.KieScanner;
import org.kie.api.builder.ReleaseId;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class DroolsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public KieContainer kieContainer() {
        KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
        ReleaseId releaseId = kieServices.newReleaseId("com.drools", "drools-rules-test", "2.0.0-SNAPSHOT");

        KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(releaseId);
        KieScanner scanner = kieServices.newKieScanner(kieContainer);
        scanner.start(1000);
        return kieContainer;
    }
}

We've tried to replicate it and create a simple projects with simple rule jar to replicate the issue then debug it using intelliJ. We found that the drools-compiler dependency first look inside the classPath for kieModule then proceed to check local repository.
  URL kmoduleUrl = contextClassLoader.getResource( KieModuleModelImpl.KMODULE_JAR_PATH.asString() );

this line of code produces this path:
nested:/Users/isaacjones/IdeaProjects/drools-test/target/drools-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar/!BOOT-INF/lib/drools-rules-test-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

due to wrong format for the classLoader the "!" in the .jar/!BOOT-INF and dependency lookup for the path it defaults to a default artifact that doesn't exist.
        if (pomReleaseId.equals(releaseId)) {
            String path = pomPropertiesUrl.getPath();
            String pathToJar = path.substring( 0, path.indexOf( ".jar!" ) + 4 );


We're expecting that the class loader able to produce this correct path in order to work and procced to check the .m2 repository for the jar.
nested:/Users/isaacjones/IdeaProjects/drools-test/target/drools-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/drools-rules-test-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

What causes the wrong contextClassLoader path for JAVA 17? since this not happens in JAVA 8 with drools 7.
Is there any missing kie or drools dependency in order to solve this issue?
Any help and answer is very much appreciated!
